# Why do I get the error: "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'"?

Tags: python, arrays, list, floating-point

I'm trying to code a calculator that prints relative and absolute error,. In the final step of the algorithm I need to create a new list to retain the new values of Y but I'm getting the error:

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

This is the code: ‍

```
#Metodo de minimos cuadrados 

#Crear lista
lstx = []
lsty = []

#Numero de elementos den el input 
n = int(input("¿Cuantos valores desea ingresar?"))

#Arreglo de x
for i in range (0,n):
        x = float(input("Ingrese los valores de x: "))
        lstx.append(float(x))
sumx = sum(lstx)

#Arreglo de y
for a in range (0,n):
        y = float(input("Ingrese los valores de y: "))
        lsty.append(float(y))
sumy = sum(lsty)

#Generamos lista de xy
lstxy = [x*y for x,y in zip(lstx,lsty)]
sumxy = sum(lstxy)

#Generamos lista de x^2
lst2 = [n**2 for n in lstx]
sum2 = sum(lst2)

#Calcular la pendiente
m = (sumxy - (sumx*sumy)/n) / (sum2 - (sumx*sumx)/n)

#Calcular la intercepción
promx = sumx / len(lstx)
promy = sumy / len(lsty)
b = promy - (m*promx)

#Obtener los nuevos valores de y
new = [(m*lstx)+b]
newY = []
for item in new:
        newY.append(float(item))
```

Comment: Why do you think you should *not* get this error?

Answer (score 0):

As Python has a lot of different data types, such as int, float, list... - you can't use their collaboration wherever you want. You can use type() function to get a data type of your variable and see where is a problem.

```
print(type(m))
print(type(lstx))
print(type(b))
```

"m" and "b" variables are floats. "lstx" is list. You can *multiply* integer with list (**not float with list**) and you can't do *plus* operation between list and not list.